# R Dplyr: How to replace items in a vector matching items in a list, conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr, match

As requested by a collaborator, I am trying to create a second version of a dataset with outliers removed. I have data with multiple groups (factors) and multiple numeric response variables. I want to write a function that (1) finds outliers and extremes by group using the 1.5*IQR and 3* IQR methods, (2) counts the outliers, and (3) if the number of outliers is greater than 2, replaces values for EXTREMES only with `NA`, but if the number of outliers is less than or equal to 2, replaces values for OUTLIERS with `NA`.

Because this is a grouped calculation, I have opted to use dplyr. I am hoping to apply this function to each of the several response variables in my dataset. I have achieved steps (1) and (2) with this method, but am facing the following issues with step (3).

Steps 1 and 2:

```
require(dplyr)

# Find outliers and extremes for one response variable by group. Mark if number of outliers per group is >2. 
# List outliers and extremes.
out_ext_num <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = (Sepal.Length < summary(Sepal.Length)[2] - (1.5*IQR(Sepal.Length)) | 
                         (Sepal.Length > ((1.5*IQR(Sepal.Length)) + summary(Sepal.Length)[5]))),
         is_extreme = (Sepal.Length < (summary(Sepal.Length)[2] - (3*IQR(Sepal.Length)))) | 
           (Sepal.Length > ((3*IQR(Sepal.Length)) + summary(Sepal.Length)[5]))) %>%
  summarise(out_num2 = sum(is_outlier) > 2, outliers = list(Sepal.Length[is_outlier == T]), 
            extremes = list(Sepal.Length[is_extreme == T]))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    out_num2 outliers  extremes 
  <fct>      <lgl>    <list>    <list>   
1 setosa     FALSE    <dbl [0]> <dbl [0]>
2 versicolor FALSE    <dbl [0]> <dbl [0]>
3 virginica  FALSE    <dbl [1]> <dbl [0]>
```

I can combine this with a nested version of my data so that the groups line up:
(EDITED)

```
nested <- iris %>%
  select(Species, Sepal.Length) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>%
  left_join(out_ext_num)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    data              out_num2 outliers  extremes 
  <fct>      <list>            <lgl>    <list>    <list>   
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 1]> FALSE    <dbl [0]> <dbl [0]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 1]> FALSE    <dbl [0]> <dbl [0]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 1]> FALSE    <dbl [1]> <dbl [0]>
```

Now, for each group, if `out_num2` is `FALSE`, I want to match values from the `data` tibble (containing vector `Sepal.Length`) with values from the `outliers` list. If they match, I want to replace that value in the tibble with `NA`. If `out_num2` is `TRUE`, I want to match values from the `data` tibble with values from the `extremes` list and replace corresponding values in the tibble with `NA`. Right now, I can't even match values from the list with the tibble, period, let alone do it conditionally. I have tried using `%in%` within `mutate()` and `map()`, but sense that I am incorrectly referencing the `Sepal.Length` vector within the tibble:

```
require(purrr)

nested %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length.o = map(data, ~ ifelse(Sepal.Length[.x %in% nested$outliers], NA, Sepal.Length)))
```

I've reviewed list referencing and several posts on matching values from different sites, but nothing quite works with this dplyr format. Is there another or better way to do this?

After figuring out how to match, I was planning to use nested `ifelse` statements to conditionally replace outlier or extreme values with `NA`, perhaps similar to this:

```
nested %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length.o = ifelse(out_num2 == T, 
                         ifelse(match_tibble_with_extremes, NA, Sepal.Length),
                         ifelse(match_tibble_with_outliers, NA, Sepal.Length)))
```

But I'm not sure if that will work as I intend. Any help, especially with the matching step, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `out_num`

Comment: That should be `out_ext_num`. I've edited it in the post. Thank you.

Comment: In your example, all the rows have `out_num2` as FALSE

Comment: That is the case for the iris dataset, but for my own data, I may get some TRUEs, depending on the dataset.

Comment: You can try `nested %>% rowwise %>% mutate(data = map2(data, if(out_num2) list(extremes) else list(outliers),  ~ replace(.x, .x %in% .y, NA)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nested %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(data = map2(data, if(out_num2) list(extremes) else list(outliers),  ~ replace(.x, .x %in% .y, NA)))
```